# How to make a forward compatible (Service Fabric) microservice

Tags: deployment, microservices, azure-service-fabric

According to [Service Fabric rolling upgrades documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade):

> During the upgrade, the cluster may contain a mix of the old and new versions.  For that reason, the two versions must be forward and backward compatible.

I know how to make a microservice backward compatible so an old client can talk to a new server. But how can an old server be (forward) compatible with a new client, which can try to call a newly introduced endpoint?

The documentation follows with:

> If they are not compatible, the application administrator is responsible for staging a multiple-phase upgrade to maintain availability

Is a multiple-phase upgrade the only way of achieving high availability when introducing new endpoints in a microservice? or can it be achieved with the default rolling upgrade process, maybe by routing the calls from new clients to new servers?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about introducing new endpoints. It's about handling existing endpoints.

Let's say you have and endpoint E1 which returns 2 fields, F1 and F2. Now, you introduced a new feature that requires E1 returning 3 fields - F1, F2, F3.

If you're doing rolling upgrade, you have both old and new clients talking to both old and new server. If in a particular communication, an old client gets connected to a new server and the client breaks by seeing a new field F3, it is NOT forward compatible.

So, forward compatibility is where the old client can read data created by new client.

For e.g. while parsing JSON using Jackson, we can specify `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` which will ignore new properties. Similarly while using other data encoding formats like Apache Thrift or Protocol Buffer, we can add new fields while maintaining forward compatibility, but if we remove existing fields, compatibility breaks. With Avro, things are little easier as the schema used to encode data is available with the data.

Martin Klepmann's book [Designing data intensive applications](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06XPJML5D/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1) has a detailed chapter on this.

Comment: i think you might be wrong, forward compatibility means old service provider(old server) should able to take input from new consumer( consumer that depends new server features and sends new input) , so the old service provider should be take the new input  and still be able to compatible and not break